# passbook skip to specified pass

Tags: ios, passbook

hello，when i add a pass to passbook,then i want to view it at the passbook i use:

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[[passLib passWithPassTypeIdentifier:[pass passTypeIdentifier] serialNumber:[pass serialNumber]] passURL]];

                                NSLog(@"coupon:%@",[pass serialNumber]);
```

when i add only one pass to passbook ,all is ok.but when i add other pass to passbooks,it skip to the first pass,not the new pass,i  am use scorecard.when i use coupon card all is ok,through i can add many coupon pass to passbook,it can skip specified pass.but i use  scorecard style ,when i add many pass,it  cannot skip the  specified pass.

my serialNumber all are different.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running? There was a bug that has since been fixed in the latest beta

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest beta and see if this fixed your problem.

Comment: why not answer my question,i can  receive it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of iOS are you running? There was a bug in the current production version that has since been fixed in the latest beta.

Try upgrading to the latest beta and see if this fixed your problem.